# How to use lua-filter with bookdown gitbook output?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have an example bookdown project with gitbook output

index.Rmd:

```
---
title: "An Example Project"
author: "Coderoo"
output:
  bookdown::gitbook: default
    pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter=hello.lua"]
documentclass: book
---

Some text {{helloworld}}
```

hello.lua is taken straight from the pandoc lua-filter doc:

```
return {
  {
    Str = function (elem)
      if elem.text == "{{helloworld}}" then
        return pandoc.Emph {pandoc.Str "Hello, World"}
      else
        return elem
      end
    end,
  }
}
```

But when I try to build the book:

```
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd','bookdown::gitbook')"
```

I get this error:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 5, column 16
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Please delete _main.Rmd after you finish debugging the error.
Execution halted
```

If I replace `bookdown::gitbook default` in the YAML metadata with `html_document` then everything works fine.

Crossposted here as well: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-use-lua-filter-with-gitbook-output/48256

EDIT: Answered in the rstudio forum.

Comment: Already answered on the Rstudio forum.